# error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry (R)

Tags: java, r, rjava

I am trying to follow the instructions from this page to perform "rule mining": https://rdrr.io/cran/rCBA/man/fpgrowth.html :

```
#load library
library(rCBA)
library(rJava)

#load data
data("iris")

#format data
train <- sapply(iris,as.factor)
train <- data.frame(train, check.names=FALSE)
txns <- as(train,"transactions")

#run the desired procedure
rules = rCBA::fpgrowth(txns, support=0.03, confidence=0.03, maxLength=2, consequent="Species",
           parallel=FALSE)
```

This returns the following error:

```
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
```

I tried to install/uninstall the necessary packages, but the error is persisting. Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

I have posted the systems log from my R session below:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new directory in C: drive as "library"
2. set your libPath this directory. you need to type

.libPath("C:/library")

3. reinstall packages which requires java (xlsx, rJava, RJDemetra)
4. it will give error message again but it will work.